# USB Camera is not detected by OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, usb-camera

I am working on a project that has to detect a USB camera (CM3-U3-13S2C-CS a 1.3 Megapixel USB 3.0 camera), opencv failed to detect the id of the camera I have tried the code below to display the IDS of available cameras but all that openCV detects is the ID of the webcam, the camera is working fine on Labview.
I would really appreciate any help !

```
> import cv2
> 
> openCvVidCapIds = []
> 
> for i in range(100):
>     try:
>         cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
>         if cap is not None and cap.isOpened():
>             openCvVidCapIds.append(i)
>         # end if
>     except:
>         pass
>     # end try
> # end for
> 
> print(str(openCvVidCapIds))
```

Comment: You can't open the device 100 times.

Comment: @Asky. What if you remove if cap is not None and replace this while cap.isOpenewd():?

Comment: @KlausD. The code lists the available Cameras IDs  instead of typing each time random values to find the right Id of the concerned camera , in my case it gave me the Id of the Pc webcam. (0)
I guess the issue is as mentionned paulyang0125, the usb camera is not recognized by the  device manager.

Comment: @toyotaSupra still gives the Id of the webcam, the issue here is not about the code, even without the code I tried random numbers to detect the USB camera but no number was the right one, so I guess the problem is ( as mentioned Paul ) the camera is not recognized by the system

Comment: @KlausD. they're obviously not doing that, but trying to open each of those ID once.

Comment: if your system doesn't even see the camera device, it's not an OpenCV issue. USB UVC works "without drivers", but "USB3 Vision" and other industrial stuff doesn't do that. you've kept the brand and model of your camera a secret, so we can't help you google for this.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your response. I don't know what you mean by me keeping the model of the camera a secret when I have already mentioned it in my post..

Comment: 1) The camera must connect to an interface card. This is sometimes called a host adapter, a bus controller, or a network
interface card (NIC).

Comment: 2) In order to achieve the maximum benefits of USB 3.0, the camera must connect to a USB 3.0 PCIe 2.0 card

Comment: 3) You must purchase a compatible card.  Sorry, Asky.  Listen to Christoph

Comment: ah, so that was the model? I mistook that, sorry. spec sheet says it's only supporting "USB3 Vision v1.0", so that means it does **not** do UVC, so it's **not a webcam**, the OS doesn't recognize it as a video source, just a non-specific USB device. you need drivers for this thing. if you're lucky, one of the `videoio` backends in OpenCV may support this, even if it's named badly. some of the "proprietary" backends are actually just "USB3 Vision". when in doubt, call the manufacturer.

Comment: try the XIMEA backend. internet rumor says the company has devices that do USB3 Vision, so it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which OS are you running your OpenCV codes? have you checked if your USB camera is shown up in your OS device layers?

- for windows, in the Device Manager under the "Imaging devices" tree
- for Linux, in /dev like "/dev/video1" and "/dev/video2" and then do

  cap =
  cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/videox")

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ! I think this is the issue, I didn't find the USB camera as a device neither in Cameras nor in Imaging devices.. I guess I have to install the driver first?
I work on Windows for now

Comment: @Asky my pleasure! yes, you need the windows driver support. you can also verify vlc media player (http://www.breakthrusoftware.com/html/onlinedocs/kb/videomill/VLC.html) to see if it can pick the USB camera. If vlc doesn't see it, you have to deal with the driver first

Comment: @paulyang0125. Sorry. You have to purchase video card from company.